# Running a code for each MySQL table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code below which I use to select datas from multiple table

```
SELECT id as id, date as date FROM table1 UNION SELECT id as id, date as date FROM table2 ORDER BY date DESC
```

It works fine, but now I need to know which table each `id` is coming from so I can use an `IF` condition. So I came out with this code

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id as id, date as date FROM table1 as tab UNION SELECT id as id, date as date FROM table2 as tab ORDER BY date DESC");
While($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $id = $sql['id'];
    $table = $sql['tab'];

    if($table == 'table1'){
        // Run code for table1
    } else if($table == 'table2'){
        // Run code for table2
    }
}
```

But I get an error of undefined index `tab`

Comment: it will come from table 2, BTW you need to change query to distinguish them like `.... UNION SELECT id as table2_id,......`

Comment: id as table_1id id as table_2id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `id`, `date` as date, 'table1' as tbname FROM table1
UNION
SELECT `id`, `date` as date, 'table2' as tbname FROM table2 ORDER BY date DESC
```

Then just read the tbname column.

Answer (score 0):

Add a static field for each source table.

```
SELECT t1.id as id, t1.date as date, '1' as src
    FROM table1 t1
UNION 

SELECT t2.id as id, t2.date as date, '2' as src 
    FROM table2 t2 

ORDER BY date DESC
```

Now you are able to filter for 1 or 2.